# Using mapGetters in TypeScript and Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I can't find a straight answer on this and I'm not very good at TS. How can I convert these computed property in Vue to be used in a TypeScript file?

```
  computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
         getLoggedInUserFirstName: "Common/getLoggedInUserFirstName",
         getLoggedInUserLastName: "Common/getLoggedInUserLastName"
      })
  }
```

Comment: Does [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-set-up-and-code-nuxt-js-apps-fully-in-typescript/) helps? scroll down to Vuex at bottom.

Comment: Would you like to use this inside a component or inside a TS file?

Comment: @Charlie A Vue component file. Inside the TS script. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @LOTUSMS comments he said he is using inside a Vue file.

Well, you have two options here. If you are using the class-based syntax a.k.a:

```
@Component({})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  ...
}
```

you can do the following:

```
@Component({
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      getLoggedInUserFirstName: "Common/getLoggedInUserFirstName",
      getLoggedInUserLastName: "Common/getLoggedInUserLastName"
    })
  }
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  // if you can you can denote the type with:
  // public getLoggedInUserFirstName!: string;
  public getLoggedInUserFirstName!;

  public getLoggedInUserLastName!;
}
```

If you are using the extend version you can use it simplyly as you were using before:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      getLoggedInUserFirstName: "Common/getLoggedInUserFirstName",
      getLoggedInUserLastName: "Common/getLoggedInUserLastName"
    })
  }
})
</script>
```